# electron context menu BuildFromTemplate with function

Tags: javascript, electron, contextmenu

i made function return a menu option.
it works, but return error.

my code:

```
const { remote } = require('electron')
const { Menu } = remote
const tabTemplate = require("./menuTemplates/tabTemplate")

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.target.id === "tabListItem") {
        let menuTest = Menu.buildFromTemplate(tabTemplate(e)) //i get error here

        menuTest.popup({ window: remote.getCurrentWindow() })
    }
}, false)
```

tabTemplate.js

```
function template(clickedElement) {
    return [
        {
            label: 'Delete',
            click: function () { alert(clickedElement) }
        }
    ]
}

module.exports = template
```

error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: tabTemplate is not a function
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, it should work. Can you do a `console.log(typeof tabTemplate)` just after the import and just before the usage? Maybe you override it somewhere.

Comment: it return object

Comment: At which position does it say `object`? Check just after the import, and just before the usage.